# Main partition and Mounting point

Tags: partitioning, mount

I've discovered that the Linux "runable" partition of my desktop PC has only 255 MB and it is mounted at /boot.

This is absolutely different to my laptop PC HDD configuration.

I can't change it. I can't resize it, I can't move it to another point and I can't eliminate it.

Why this partition is so small? How can I put it into another point, and with more big space?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!

Juan

Answer (score 1):

**/boot** partition is your partition with kernels and grub loader. Actually no needs to increase it, just clean old kernels from time to time. https://askubuntu.com/a/254585/217142

PS. You can increase it but from Live CD or like that.